# Receiving NSException when trying to change UITabBar icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem, unrecognized-selector

I have a UINavigationController that displays a UITabBarController. I am trying to add custom icons for the tab bars. I have placed the following code in AppDelegate.m `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconSelected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem1.title = nil;
```

With this code I receive the following NSException:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController tabBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faed26343e0'

My assumption is that somehow in `*tabBar` I need to access the tabBar through the UINavigationController. (I.E. - `UITabBar *tabBar = UINavigationController.tabBarController.tabBar;`) However, this does not work either.

What is the proper way to achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: Your `rootViewController` isn't a `UITabBarController`, it's a `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `tabBarController` is within a navigation controller, you need to get a reference to it from that navigation controller.  It can be found as the first object in the navigation controllers' `viewControllers` property (or, if no other controllers have been pushed onto the navigation controller, the `topViewController` property).  Replace:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

with:

```
UINavigationController *navCtrl = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)navCtrl.viewControllers[0];
```

Comment: This code produces [LaunchScreenViewController tabBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. LaunchScreenViewController is the VC immediately after my UINavigationController. Why would it be calling this LaunchScreenVC as it is not my very first VC? @pbasdf

Comment: Sorry, I assumed your sequence was NavController -> TabBarController .  What is the actual sequence?

Comment: The sequence is:
UINavigationController >
LaunchScreenVC >
SignUpVC & LogInVC >
UITabBarController >
UserProfileVC & Contacts VC

I tried to upload a picture of my storyboard but I currently do not have enough reputation points. I hope that you are able to visualize it. @pbasdf

Comment: Wow, so that tabBarVC is a long way down the tree.  Do you really want to set its tabBar from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?  Can't you set it all in the storyboard?

Comment: I didn't realize that it could be set from storyboard. Thanks for the help! @pbasdf